# Kdenlive 22.08.3 Stabilize menu item missing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, kdenlive

I am running Kdenlive 22.08.3 on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop. I have a video clip which I want to stabilize. When selecting this clip I should get a "Stabilize" menu item in the menu Clip -> Clip Jobs. However, this menu item is not present. The Clip Jobs menu only includes "Automatic Scene Split" and "Duplicate Clip with Speed Change".
I do have the ffmpeg package installed on my computer.
What else do I need to get this Stabilize menu item?

Edit: one of the comments guided me to a solution: upgrading Kdenlive to a newer version made this menu item available. Using the Software app I noticed that I could choose from various versions. I selected version 22.12.2 to be installed on my computer. This version had the Sabilize menu item.

Comment: Do not know where you got this software from but the web site says 22.12 was released in Dec. 2022.

Comment: Seems you use Kdenlive as a snap. Try the deb-package ( `sudo apt install kdenlive`), it's a slightly older version but with it I have the `Stabilize` menu item even without selecting a clip.

Comment: Thank you David. I removed version 22.08.3 and installed 22.12.2. This version does have the Stabilize menu item.

Comment: Thank you mook765. I looked in Software and noticed that there are multiple versions of Kdenlive available. I removed the one I had and replaced it with a newer version (22.12.2). This solved my issue.

Comment: @Joe Since using a newer version solved your issue, could you add an answer (which you can also mark as the solution) with a bit more details on how you installed the newer version? This should be helpful to other people with the same issue. Thanks! :)